# Animations not starting directly after method call

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation

In my app delegate I perform my `updateData` method using `performSelecorInBackground:withObject`. At the end, a notification is posted which tells an observer in my tableview to reload the data.

My problem is with the animations: using the code below, my animations start at the end of the method and not directly after `performSelector`.

Does this have something to do with backgrounding the selector or is there something else I'm not seeing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
- (void) updateData: (NSString *)newVersionNumber {


    ... CODE ...


    UIView *update = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 360, 20)];
    update.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.navController.view addSubview:update];

    [self performSelector:@selector(updateDownAnimation) withObject:nil];


    ... CODE ...


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"tableviewShouldReload" object:nil];


    ... CODE ...

    [self performSelector:@selector(updateUpAnimation) withObject:nil];

}

- (void) updateDownAnimation {


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        _window.frame = CGRectOffset(_window.frame, 0, 20);

    }];

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not advisable to do UIKit stuff on secondary threads. You might want to change that to

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUpAnimation)
                       withObject:nil
                    waitUntilDone:YES];
```